# Gallery image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not asking for code or anything. I have this division below and i'm looking to make it as a slider, so upon a user click, the current display will shift to the left, and a different but same-looking division would appear. I'm new to website development, i just need some guidance on what to search for, and if any have certain links that could be beneficial. Thank you.

HTML:

```
     <div id="first">
<img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image10"src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#first
{
    display: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left: 150px;
    margin-top: -215px;
}
#first img 
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
```

Shape:
[image]

Comment: @Tushar, i tried some jquery but had some difficulties since i don't know jquery. And i downloaded jssor demos but that's not exactly what i'm looking for. I have an image for what i'm searching i'll edit the post and show you.

Comment: Then add the code in question

Comment: @Tushar it's not the required code, i was just testing to see how it works. I'm not asking for code, just some directions

Comment: Try owlcarousel http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html, It's a jQuery plugin.

Comment: @AdrianEnriquez straight to the point! Thank you!

Comment: you can try this http://jsbin.com/ufoceq/8/edit?html,output

Comment: @randy, why waste so much time coding a slider if it's already been done to death and there are dozens of awesome slider plugins. owl carousel was mentioned in one of the comments and it is perfect in my experience.

Comment: @odedta on not going to waste time on the functionalities of course.. But the design is specific

Answer (score 0):

Add some arrows on each side with left or right pictures and then try something like this, after wrapping two pictures in an overflowable-hidden-type div:

```
window.left = function () {
    $('img:first').before($('img:last').get(0).outerHTML);
    $('img:last').remove();
}
window.right = function () {
    $('img:last').before($('img:first').get(0).outerHTML);
    $('img:first').remove();
}
```

```js
$('img:even').css('opacity','.6');  // make even images lighter

window.left = function () {
    $('img:first').before($('img:last').get(0).outerHTML);  // copy the last picture before the first one.
    $('img:last').remove();  // remove the last picture from the end of the stack.
}
window.right = function () {
    $('img:last').before($('img:first').get(0).outerHTML);  // copy the first picture after the last one.
    $('img:first').remove();  // remove the first picture from the beginning of the stack
}
```

```css
html {
    font-size: 50px;
}
#first {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 150px;
    width: 740px;
}
img {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p onclick="left()">
                <</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="first" style="display:inline-block;">
                <img id="image1" src="https://coderwall-assets-0.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/file/1824/350x150.gif" />
                <img id="image2" src="https://coderwall-assets-0.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/file/1824/350x150.gif" />
                <img id="image3" src="https://coderwall-assets-0.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/file/1824/350x150.gif" />
                <img id="image4" src="https://coderwall-assets-0.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/file/1824/350x150.gif" />
                <img id="image5" src="https://coderwall-assets-0.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/file/1824/350x150.gif" />
                <img id="image6" src="https://coderwall-assets-0.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/file/1824/350x150.gif" />
                <img id="image7" src="https://coderwall-assets-0.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/file/1824/350x150.gif" />
                <img id="image8" src="https://coderwall-assets-0.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/file/1824/350x150.gif" />
                <img id="image9" src="https://coderwall-assets-0.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/file/1824/350x150.gif" />
                <img id="image10" src="https://coderwall-assets-0.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/file/1824/350x150.gif" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p onclick="right()">></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Regarding the snippet, it works, I just used the same picture for everything, so I made the even ones lighter in hue.